# How do i return the result of all regular expression? I need to return results of all android phones from "description" and "product"

Tags: python, regex

I created define by searchbybrand. Under the products, I have android and apple. When user selects "android", it will return all records of android. And I used regrex and if-else statement.

```py
    def searchbybrand(string):
      if string == "android":
        return 
(collected_data[collected_data['description'].astype(str).str.contains('[Aa]ndroid')])
```

However, the define function could not return the records for the elif. It only returns the result of "description", but not "product" based on the regrex.

```py
      elif string == "android":
        return (collected_data[collected_data['product'].astype(str).str.contains('[Aa]ndroid|[Aa]mazon')])
```

```
      else:
        return collected_data[collected_data['product'].astype(str).str.contains('[Aa]pple|[Ii]Pad|[Rr]etina|[Aa]ir')]
```

Therefore, when I search by "android", it returns only the result from "description" and not "product".

```py
    searchbybrand('android')
```

The result:

```
price   description product review
0   $69.99  7" screen, Android  Lenovo IdeaTab  7 reviews
1   $88.99  Black, 7" IPS, Quad-Core 1.2GHz, 8GB, Android 4.2   IdeaTab A3500L  7 reviews
2   $96.99  7" screen, Android, 16GB    Acer Iconia 7 reviews
3   $97.99  7", 8GB, Wi-Fi, Android 4.2, White  Galaxy Tab 3    2 reviews
4   $99.99  Black, 7", 1.6GHz Dual-Core, 8GB, Android 4.4   Iconia B1-730HD 1 reviews
5   $101.99 IPS, Dual-Core 1.2GHz, 8GB, Android 4.3 Memo Pad HD 7   10 reviews
6   $102.99 7" screen, Android, 8GB Asus MeMO Pad   14 reviews
8   $107.99 7", 8GB, Wi-Fi, Android 4.2, Yellow Galaxy Tab 3    14 reviews
9   $121.99 Blue, 8" IPS, Quad-Core 1.3GHz, 16GB, Android 4.2   IdeaTab A8-50   13 reviews
10  $130.99 White, 7", Atom 1.2GHz, 8GB, Android 4.4    MeMO Pad 7  11 reviews
11  $148.99 Blue, 7" IPS, Quad-Core 1.3GHz, 8GB, 3G, Andro...   IdeaTab A3500-H 9 reviews
12  $172.99 Silver, 7" IPS, Quad-Core 1.2Ghz, 16GB, 3G, An...   IdeaTab S5000   8 reviews
15  $320.99 White, 10.1" IPS, 1.6GHz, 2GB, 16GB, Android 4.2    MeMo PAD FHD 10 7 reviews
16  $399.99 10.1", 3G, Android 4.0, Garnet Red  Galaxy Note 12 reviews
17  $489.99 12.2", 32GB, WiFi, Android 4.4, White   Galaxy Note 9 reviews
```

Comment: It appears you may be using pandas (collected_data looks like a global reference to a data frame)- you have not stated that.  Can you provide example code to populate data frame

Answer (score 0):

Review your logic.  In your requirement you really state that you want a union of rows where *brand* is in either *product* or *description* column.  Code as such.   Your sample data doesn't contain these conditions - row 0 and row 999 synthesised for this test

```
import re
import pandas as pd
data = '''row  price   description  product  review
0   $69.99  7" screen, Google  Lenovo IdeaTab  7 reviews
1   $88.99  Black, 7" IPS, Quad-Core 1.2GHz, 8GB, Android 4.2   IdeaTab A3500L  7 reviews
2   $96.99  7" screen, Android, 16GB    Acer Iconia  7 reviews
3   $97.99  7", 8GB, Wi-Fi, Android 4.2, White  Galaxy Tab 3    2 reviews
4   $99.99  Black, 7", 1.6GHz Dual-Core, 8GB, Android 4.4   Iconia B1-730HD  1 reviews
5   $101.99  IPS, Dual-Core 1.2GHz, 8GB, Android 4.3  Memo Pad HD 7   10 reviews
6   $102.99  7" screen, Android, 8GB Asus  MeMO Pad   14 reviews
8   $107.99  7", 8GB, Wi-Fi, Android 4.2, Yellow  Galaxy Tab 3    14 reviews
9   $121.99  Blue, 8" IPS, Quad-Core 1.3GHz, 16GB, Android 4.2   IdeaTab A8-50   13 reviews
10  $130.99  White, 7", Atom 1.2GHz, 8GB, Android 4.4    MeMO Pad 7  11 reviews
11  $148.99  Blue, 7" IPS, Quad-Core 1.3GHz, 8GB, 3G, Andro...   IdeaTab A3500-H  9 reviews
12  $172.99  Silver, 7" IPS, Quad-Core 1.2Ghz, 16GB, 3G, An...   IdeaTab S5000   8 reviews
15  $320.99  White, 10.1" IPS, 1.6GHz, 2GB, 16GB, Android 4.2    MeMo PAD FHD 10  7 reviews
16  $399.99  10.1", 3G, Android 4.0, Garnet Red  Galaxy Note  12 reviews
999  $399.99  10.1", 3G, Google 4.0, Garnet Red  Android Note  12 reviews
17  $489.99  12.2", 32GB, WiFi, Android 4.4, White   Galaxy Note  9 reviews'''
da = [[i for i in re.split("[ ][ ]+", l)] for l in data.split("\n")]
dfall = pd.DataFrame(da[1:], columns=da[0])
def searchbybrand(df, brand):
    if brand == "android": expr = "[Aa]ndroid"
    return pd.concat([df[df.description.str.contains(expr)], df[df["product"].str.contains(expr)]])

searchbybrand(dfall, "android")
```